# Handler of CloudKit's fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler never called on iOS 7 at iPhone 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cloudkit

I'm developing an app which uses user's CKRecordID as login. My app is very very simple so I wan't to support iOS 7, even though iOS 9 is about to be released, so I can support iPhones 4 too. Problem is the completion handler of `fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler` never gets called on that device, having or not iCloud setup on it.

Apple states that whatever problems happens it should be returned as an error on that block, but, as I said, the handler block never gets called on iPhone 4 running iOS 7 (unfortunatelly I can't test on other devices, nor iPhone Simulator as I'm running 10.11 and Xcode 7).

Maybe a bug?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: CloudKit is only available from iOS 8 and later. Not in iOS 7.

Comment: Wow, shame on me. Thank you!